# Why 1-based cycle and then subtracting one?

Tags: c#, programming-practices

In a book that deals with mutually orthogonal latin squares, there is an example of implementation of a generator.
The part of the code is as follows:

```
for (int k = 1; k <= numberOfLevels; k++) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
            squareArray[k - 1][i - 1,j - 1] = ( k * (i - 1) + (j - 1) ) % size;
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder, why `i=1` and `j=1` and then subtracting `1`? For `k` I understand that it is used for multiplication.

Comment: It is possibly just for consistent with mathematical (textbook) notations for matrices. If the book has a preface or appendix that explains its choice of notations or conventions, please take a look.

Comment: IMO this is just bad style; in almost every language where arrays are 0-based the idiomatic loop is over the half-closed [0, limit) range. The only excuse here is if this is a straight implementation of an algorithm, which strictly follows some formulas that are 1-based.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Some languages are not, some code bases are not, and yes some specifications are not. The excuse here is established convention. If this is a context where it's following an established convention then fine.  If we're free to chose without being the odd one out then only flagellation justifies this. Icky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a choice of code style that perhaps the author thought would be clearer. You could easily rewrite it as

```
for (int k = 0; k < numberOfLevels; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            squareArray[k][i,j] = ((k+1) * (i + j)) % size;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that we intuitively think of lists as going from 1 to N, where N is the number of elements. But all arrays in c# are base 0, so we'd have to subtract. You can either subtract when declaring the loop (as I have done) or subtract when using the loop variables (as the original author does).

I think perhaps the author chose to subtract when using the loop variables because there are places where he actually needs the original index number (from 1 to N), e.g. when computing the modulus of the size.

Comment: If you mix 0-based and 1-based indices in closely spaced (or nested) loops, you should rename the variables for clarity:  e.g.  `for (int k1based = 1; k1based <= numberOfLevels...`

Comment: Hmm I don't think this is a perfect refactoring. We've gone from starting at `squareArray[0][0,0]` to starting at `squareArray[1][0,0]`

Comment: Oops.  Fixed it.

Comment: Better, now fix the fact that you've added 2 not 1 to the right hand terms (i & j) of the assignment.

Comment: Nicely done. Oh and @user949300, You really shouldn't mix bases for indices without a darn good reason. Name mangling is more a band-aid than a fix. It's just another symptom of a very bad problem.

Comment: @CandiedOrange agree completely, I was **not advocating** mixing indices, the (original) answer was and earned my downvote.   Rewrite is way better and flips my downvote to an upvote.